# Javascript validation for a contact field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to validate a field that can either contain an email address or a phone number. How would would one go about doing this? I feel my code is close but im a little stuck on the numbers part.

```
   if (($(this).find('#contactPhoneEmail').val().indexOf('@') != -1) && ($(this).find('#contactPhoneEmail').val().indexOf('@') != -1)){
      alert("You did not enter a valid contact type"); 
      return false; // prevents submitting
    }
```

In pseudocode i am trying something like the following:

"If the field does not contain '@' AND 'Numbers' give an alert"

I understand that it is not completely fullproof, but it will atleast prevent people entering alphabet characters. My form uses the same field to allow people to choose either an email address or a phone number. I also considered to do something like the following

"If it does contain only numbers, then make sure it is the correct format" However i realise that there are a variety of phone number types, and it would seem impossible to make sure.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Use a regexp. Find a regexp for email, another regexp for phone number, then combine them with `|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
function isEmail (s) {
    var isEmail_re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    return String(s).search (isEmail_re) != -1;
}

function isPhoneNumber (s) {
    var isPhoneNumber_re = /^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/;
    return String(s).search (isPhoneNumber_re) != -1;
}
```

Your validate function would then be like this:

```
function validate () {
     var input = $(this).find('#contactPhoneEmail').val();
     return isEmail(input) || isPhoneNumber(input);
}
```

Comment: what would your function validate() return? I.e. how do i test for it? Should it be "if validate == false then alert "

Comment: validate() returns true if the input was either an email or a phone number. If input is neither then validate() will return false. You can test it just like you said, by using if validate() == false then alert.

Comment: I thought so :) unfortunately it is returning false for valid email addresses

Comment: i think i know where the problem is. It wasnt getting my value into the function. If it my fix works, ill post your response as the answer

Comment: I tested isEmail() and isPhoneNumber() and they both passed. Maybe you need to tweak the 'validate' function to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go about it like this

```
function submit_form() {
    if (validate()) {
        // ajax send or submit form.
    }
}

function validate() {
    field = $('.some-div').val();

    if (field.match("/emailRegex/i") || field.match("/phoneRegex/i")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

there are plenty of regex (regular expressions) out there on the internet, I'd say look for some which you are happy with.

also there are a few ways to submit your form. You can bind the `submit_form()` function to your submit button and make it send your form with the data or make it cancel the form submission and send it if the validation passes.

edit - slightly misread question.

Comment: It seems your code requires me two have two input fields, however my code has 1 input field called "Enter a phone or email".

Answer (score 0):

if your logic is to check one field, and if it has a '@' in it, you can assume it is a valid email, or if it does not have a '@' in it, then it can only be numbers (i.e. 0-9) then something like the following should achieve your goal.

```
function checkPhoneEmailValid()
{
    var phoneEmailValue = $('#contactPhoneEmail').val();
    var regExTester = /@|^[0-9]+$/; //This is a Regular Expression that checks for the occurance of a @
                                    // or the whole string only contain numbers 0-9
    return regExTester.test(phoneEmailValue); //This will return true or false;
}
```

Although these rules are very basic, and there are much better ways to test for an email and /or phonenumber. Also you need to be sure what characters you allow for a phone number, if you include country codes or area codes then the regex will need to change. Google regex for phone number/email and you will find more comprehensive options